# Multiple Zookeeper/Kafka setups on same host

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to have this setup on the same Ubuntu host machine with Kafka 3.3.0:

- zookeeper, port 2181
- kafka1, port 9092
- kafka2, port 9093
- kafka3, port 9094

and

- zookeeper, port 2182
- kafka4, port 9095
- kafka5, port 9096
- kafka6, port 9097

I want them to act like 2 separate environments, despite being on the same host.

I can run each "set" at time, but when I fire them both up, I see the following issues:

1. All of the topics from the first set of Kafka servers are no longer accessible via Kafka clients, even though the logs are still on the file system.  Running `kafka-topics --list` returns no data.
2. Kafka and Zookeeper services crash (`sudo systemctl status zookeeper` shows failure for all 8 services)

**Is it possible to run 2 discrete setups like this on 1 host**?  I've done the following, but it doesn't seem to be enough:

- In both zookeeper.properties files, change the `dataDir` and `clientPort`
- In all 6 Kafka server.properties files, change the `broker.id`, `listeners`, `advertised.listeners`,  `zookeeper.connect` and `log.dirs` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Can I remove my question?  This plagued me for a week.  Then, once I asked this question here, it miraculously started working out of nowhere (I didn't touch anything the past few days).